# Phonegap Android (Not showing google ad on android HD phones)

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, adsense

I have created a phonegap app for ios and android,In my ios app google add showing perfect but it didn't show add in android HD Device .Below is my code which i have put in phonegap code google add.

```
<script type="text/javascript">google_ad_client = "ca-pub-1334072329832035";``
google_ad_slot = "6009211105";
google_ad_width = 320;
google_ad_height = 50;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of AdSense for mobile content in a mobile application is a violation of AdSense policies. A mobile application constitutes any downloadable application, even if a WebView is used to display the ad. Any AdSense for mobile content ad units found in mobile applications will be disabled. If you’re looking for an advertising solution for your mobile application, please sign up for AdMob, Google’s leading mobile advertising display product.

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the policies? They define a "mobile application" and explicitly state that use of WebView does not make it not an app. I quote:

The use of AdSense for mobile content in a mobile application is a violation of AdSense policies. A mobile application constitutes any downloadable application, even if a WebView is used to display the ad. Any AdSense for mobile content ad units found in mobile applications will be disabled. If you’re looking for an advertising solution for your mobile application, please sign up for AdMob, Google’s leading mobile advertising display product.